# What is System Chaincode in fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I was going through the following link to understand the architecture of fabric, in which they have mentioned that "There may exist one or more special chain codes for management functions and parameters, collectively called system chain codes."

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/source/arch-deep-dive.rst

Kindly someone helps me to understand what is system chain code and what kind of functionaries are being performed by system chain code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The offical docs may help you understand it.

> System chaincodes are specialized chaincodes that run as part of the peer process as opposed to user chaincodes that run in separate docker containers. As such they have more access to resources in the peer and can be used for implementing features that are difficult or impossible to be implemented through user chaincodes

Existing system chaincodes:

- **LSCC**(Lifecycle system chaincode) handles lifecycle requests such as install, instantiate and upgrade chaincodes.
- **CSCC**(Configuration system chaincode) handles channel configuration on the peer side.
- **QSCC**(Query system chaincode) provides ledger query APIs such as getting blocks and transactions.
- **ESCC**(Endorsement system chaincode) handles endorsement by signing the transaction proposal response.
- **VSCC**(Validation system chaincode) handles the transaction validation, including checking endorsement policy and multiversioning concurrency control.

Reference pages:

- http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/systemchaincode.html
- http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4noah.html#system-chaincode