# Hyperledger Fabric: Client signature validation in a multi org setup

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to understand the transaction flow in a multi-org setup in a Fabric network. I was going through the [official document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/txflow.html).

Basically, it explains that a client creates a transaction proposal and sends it to the endorsing peers. And endorsing peers validate, simulate and endorse this transaction. During the validation phase, the endorsing peer validates the signature of the client using the MSP.

So, in the case of a single org, I understand that there will be a single MSP through which all the endorsing peers validates the signature. Also, in this case, the identity of the client is issued from the same MSP.

However, in a multi-org setup, each org maintains its own MSP. Say, we have Org1 that has endorser peers (EP1, EP2) and MSP1. In Org2, we have endorser peers(EP3, EP4) and MSP2. The endorsing policy is such that all the EPs should endorse the transaction.

In this case, the identity of the client is issued from MSP1 of Org1. So when this client submits the transaction proposal to all the endorsing peers, how will the EP3 and EP4 validate the signature of this client with their MSP2?

How these MSPs of different orgs communicate with each other for signature validations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information about the Consortium and the MSP identities are encoded in the genesis.block (file used to bootstrap the orderer) of the blockchain.

When a peer joins a channel, the request is first made to the orderer to get the information about the genesis block. With the help of this genesis block, the peer gets to know about the consortium, channel and the participants (and its MSPs)

Check this reference: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/balance-transfer/app/join-channel.js#L48

Comment: Got it. So this is a part of system chaincode, right?

Comment: No. It's not a part of the system chaincode. It's how peers join the channel. This logic to join the channel is to be built using an SDK in the client app

Comment: I see. So I'm exposing the fabric using composer instead of an SDK and the client app is just submitting the transactions. And I've used manual commands to make every peer join the channel as mentioned in "Build Your First Network" tutorial. So in that case, is it using any system chaincode to process the above logic?

Comment: No matter how you execute transactions, System chaincodes are a part of the flow, but under the hood. Read here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134059/what-is-system-chaincode-in-fabric

Comment: Right. However, if I'm using Composer REST APIs for submitting the transactions, do I need to explicitly write logic to collect endorsement signatures and validate them like mentioned in: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/balance-transfer/app/invoke-transaction.js#L52